# Encontrar determinado texto em uma string

Tags: python

Olá estou com uma duvida.

```
nome=str(input('Qual o seu nome completo?'))
print('Seu nome tem Enzo?{}'.format('Enzo' in nome.lower()))
```

Tenho esse código que ele verifica sem tem uma determinada string dentro da outra,o problema é eu quero que ele verifique sem tem um determinado nome dentro do texto em que eu digitar e faça uma determinada ação.Ex:Ver se tem a palavra "Enzo" e se tiver escrever algo na tela.

Comment: Parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sugestão para com regex seria usar o meta-caractere `\b`, exemplo:

```
import re

nome = input('Qual o seu nome completo? ')

if re.search('\\benzo\\b', nome, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("A string tem o nome Enzo")
else:
    print("A string não tem o nome Enzo")
```

O `\b` é um meta-caractere que usado para encontrar uma correspondência no início ou no final de uma palavra, evitando assim que que palavras como:

> ```
> enzon
> fenzo
> ```

Se rodar em:

```
import re

print( re.search('enzo', 'enzon', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='enzo'>
print( re.search('enzo', 'fenzo', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='enzo'>
print( re.search('enzo', 'cheetos', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna None
```

Agora usando o `\b` note como funciona:

```
import re

print( re.search('\\benzo\\b', 'enzon', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna None
print( re.search('\\benzo\\b', 'fenzo', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna None
print( re.search('\\benzo\\b', 'cheetos', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna None

print( re.search('\\benzo\\b', 'enzo foo bar', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='enzo'>
print( re.search('\\benzo\\b', 'foo enzo bar', re.IGNORECASE) ) # retorna <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 8), match='enzo'>
```

O meta-caractere `\b` é uma verdadeira mão na roda para evitar tais problemas.

Answer (score 7):

Seu código possui duas considerações importantes que não foram abordadas, de forma satisfatória, nas outras respostas.

1) Redundância na função `input`. Se você ler a [documentação oficial da função](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), verá o seguinte trecho (adaptado):

> *The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.*

Isto é, o retorno da função sempre será uma *string*, independente do conteúdo lido. Assim, fazer `str(input(...))` é inserir redundância no código e efetuar *uma*¹ chamada desnecessária a mais.

2) Sensível à caixa do texto. A comparação que você fez foi `'Enzo' in nome.lower()` e ela jamais será válida, pois você está, basicamente, buscando uma *string* com caracteres maiúsculos em uma *string* que é composta, certamente, apenas por caracteres minúsculos, visto que utilizou o método `lower()`. Seria o mesmo que buscar o número 7 em um conjunto de números pares. A lógica está certa, mas falhou na implementação.

Dito isso, seu código basicamente seria:

```
nome = input('Qual é o seu nome completo?')
print('Seu nome tem Enzo? {}'.format('Enzo' in nome))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FineBasicRefactoring) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ng71Ql) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/54f6774303b9765c9f5b99c34b92f5f0)</sup>

Porém, isso produziria uma saída tal como:

```
Seu nome tem Enzo? True
Seu nome tem Enzo? False
```

É estranho ter `True` ou `False` em meio à uma *string* em português. Pelo menos eu acho. Faria mais sentido para mim aparecer "sim" ou "não", e para isso, bastaria fazer:

```
nome = input('Qual é o seu nome completo?')
tem_enzo = 'Sim' if 'Enzo' in nome else 'Não'

print(f'Seu nome tem Enzo? {tem_enzo}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LazyLonelyDistributeddatabase) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YhjUqU) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/a1a6932166fbdacc3c5b06de7bb9444d)</sup>

Para fazer a verificação que não seja sensível à caixa, basta você utilizar o método `lower`, mas tomando o cuidado de buscar por uma *string* composta apenas por caracteres minúsculos, tal como em:

```
'enzo' in nome.lower()
```

> **Nota:** vale lembrar que este método pode não ser inteiramente eficiente, visto que retornaria como verdadeiro caso o nome do usuário fosse Lorenzo, pois possui `'enzo'` no nome. Se for interesse verificar apenas pelo termo completo, a solução seria outra.

¹ : Não é apenas uma chamada, visto que `str` é uma classe nativa do Python, não uma função. O que acontece, neste caso, é a chamada do construtor.

Comment: Se for Python2 o `input` acaso receber um numero poderá fazer o cast não? Claro que se for mesmo python2 seria interessante usar `raw_input`. Sei que parece estranho, mas ainda existem usuários da versão 2

Comment: +1 principalmente pela parte sobre o case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o if para isso, ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
nome=str(input('Qual o seu nome completo?')) 

if("Enzo" in nome):
    print("A string tem o nome Enzo")
else:
    print("A string não tem o nome Enzo")
```

Desta forma acima será sempre `case sensitive`, para ignorar isso tem essa outra opção

```
import re

nome=str(input('Qual o seu nome completo? ')) 

if re.search('enzo', nome, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("A string tem o nome Enzo")
else:
    print("A string não tem o nome Enzo")
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Para verificar ocorrências em uma string, você pode usar o count(), que contabiliza quantas vezes determinada substring é encontrada em uma string. Veja:

```
nome=input("Qual o seu nome completo?") 

if(nome.count("Enzo")):
    print("A string tem o nome Enzo")
else:
    print("A string não tem o nome Enzo")
```